# Linux problem with RAM after instalation and also live

Tags: lenovo, ram, yoga-2

I installed Linux on my *Lenovo Yoga 500* with 8GB RAM near my Windows. Windows works correctly and sees 8GB of RAM. But Linux installed on the notebook only sees 2GB RAM (1,8).

The command in the terminal: `free -m` also shows 1,8GB of RAM, but on `sudo lshw -class memory` I see my RAM stick with 8GB. `memtest` also sees 1,8GB of RAM.

I have this problem on installed Linux and on live versions (Ubuntu, Mint, Kali) from USB stick storage.

All of them are 64bit versions.
I also tried add `mem=8G` to the `grub` file, but nothing changed.

EDIT 1:
`free -m` result:

```
        total   used   free   shared    buff/cache   available
Mem:     1868   1147     79      236           641         435
Swap:       0      0      0
```

`sudo lshw -class memory` result: https://pastebin.com/1iSHbR8J

`sudo dmidecode -t memory` result: https://pastebin.com/kaMxnAXc

`cat /proc/meminfo` result: https://pastebin.com/RMTbcuU8

Comment: Please paste the exact and full outputs of the `free -m` and `sudo lshw -class memory` commands.

Comment: @ByteCommander      
 free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1868        1147          79         236         641         435
Swap:             0           0           0

Comment: @byte
for sudo lshw -class memory:
https://pastebin.com/1iSHbR8J

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information. Comments can get removed without notice and are easily missed, they also destroy all formatting. In addition to the two previously requested outputs, please also append the output of `sudo dmidecode -t memory` and `cat /proc/meminfo` to your question. Thanks.

Comment: @byte edited...

Comment: You forgot the output of `sudo dmidecode -t memory` and `cat /proc/meminfo`...

Comment: @byte ok, ready, now i didn't forget about anything

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I'm totally puzzled by your issue now. I couldn't find a clue in the information you provided. This doesn't make sense to me... :(